# PyQt5: “input” through GUI

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I was wondering if there is a function in pyqt5 that works similarly to the basic "input()" method from Python, only that it waits for an interaction with the GUI, like i.e pressing a button. 
So instead of writing something in the console, the user presses a button to relay information.

Since this question has been associated with the wrong one before I'll be clearer: I do not mean to control the GUI via the Python console. 
I want my program to wait for the user to trigger an event (i.e by pressing a button), in that sense the program asks an input that is the users interaction with the GUI.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. However PyQt does have many kinds of input widgets that allow the user to enter text, for example QLineEdit, and buttons of course.

Comment: It's alright, I was just about to try and close this as I found a way to do what I wanted to, just in case to try and be clearer, what I wanted is a method that does the same as input(), except that said input would be something like the pressing of a button.

Comment: @corlo407 your comment doesn't really clarify. Do you want to show an edit field? Do you want to display the pressed characters? What that would that button pressing do? With "button" do you mean a graphical button drawn in the interface?

Comment: Well i.e: the button is one of few QPushButton object.
The code at some point will expect the user to press any of those buttons, once that is done, depending on which button was pressed, the code will get X information.
But it's less about what the button will do, and more about the waiting for a button to be pressed.